# Interpolation in Angular preventing Reducer to be called from Action

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I am working on an Angular app which uses ngrx for State management .

I introduced a child component to the parent and noticed that reducer from ExistingAction was not getting invoked (ExistingAction) .

*ParentComponent.html*

```
...

<childComponent> </childComponent>
...
```

*ParentComponent.ts*

```
export class ParentComponent 

{

 ....

  this.store.dispatch(new ExistingAction());

...

}
```

*ChildComponent.ts*

```
    export class ChildComponent
    
    {
    
     displayString : any ;
    
    subscription$ : subscription;
    
    .... 
    
     ngOninit()
    
     {
    
       this.subscription$ = this.service.subscribe((content) => {
    
                                      this.displayString= content;
    
      }
    }
   ngOnDestroy()
   {
     this.subscription.unsubscribe();
   }
    
    ....
    
  }
```

*ChildComponent.html*

```
<label class="display">

  Sample : {{displayString['SelectSample']}}

</label>
```

**Output from the service is json like 'SelectSample' : 'This is text'**

Although the above code in ChildComponent.html prints text on the screen and no errors found in console , I found that the Reducer fn from the Action in ParentComponent was stopped being called because of introduction of ChildComponent.

After a series of trial and error I made the following change in ChildComponent and surprisingly the Reducer was invoked again and the flow worked normally .
Here is what I changed.

```
a) 

<label class="display">

          Sample : {{displayString}}

      </label>
```

-> html changes

```
b) 

this.subscription$ = this.service.subscribe((content) => {
        
                                          this.displayString= content[SelectSample];
    }
```

-> .ts changes

So my question why is usage of interpolation like this  {{displayString['SelectSample']}} , preventing the Reducer from being called ? whats the connection between interpolation and ngrx Reducers? I could not find answer anywhere for this

**WorkingCode**

```
ChildComponent.ts

export class ChildComponent

{

 displayString : any ;

subscription$ : subscription;

.... 

ngOninit()

 {

   this.subscription$ = this.service.subscribe((content) => {

                                  this.displayString= content[SelectSample];

  }
 ngOnDestroy()
 {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
 }

....

}
```

*ChildComponent.html*

```
<label class="display">

  Sample : {{displayString}}

</label>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, how exactly is the action `ExistingAction` called in the first place? How is the child component related to the parent? I see no connection. The child component has `this.service.subscribe`... to what exactly is subscribing from the service? shouldn't be something like `this.service.getSomething().subscribe` ?? And how is this related to the action being dispatched from the parent component?

Comment: Have you tried using ngOnchanges in your child component?

Answer (score 1):

It's a hard to find the root cause of this without seeing all of the code (even better is a reproduction).

But to answer the question the interpolation does not impact the "NgRx flow".
It could perhaps throw an error, which results that the action is not dispatched/view is not refreshed.